# viewmodel init fail in release apk since constructor not found

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I am using viewmodel in jetpack compose and build a factory like

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

internal class MyStateBuilder(val args: Map<String, Any?>?, val context: Context) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        try {
            Log.d("ppx",modelClass.constructors.size.toString())
            modelClass.constructors.forEach {
                Log.d("ppx",it.toGenericString())
            }
            modelClass.getConstructor(Map::class.java, Context::class.java)
            return modelClass.getConstructor(Map::class.java, Context::class.java)
                .newInstance(args, context)
        }catch (e:Exception){
            Log.e("ppx","start")
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }
    }
}
```

these codes works fine at debug compile mode, but when I goto release compile, constructor of provided class suddenly go 0 and viewModel cannot be initialized, does anybody know what happened at compile transmission?

Comment: If you are using r8/proguard, reflection is a bad idea. You are accessing constructors through reflection. avoid it or add proguard rules for it.

Comment: could you please give more info since mdoelClass is aleady provided. I don't think proguard is the answer since it only change the name but not code content, my question is viewModel cannot find its constructor

Comment: Sorry, I just did some research and found proguard does much more job than I think,    one issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149729626 looks like what I am dealing with and I will have a try